# blackberry webworks: showing captured image after taking photo

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

```
    /*******
    works when "Take Photo" button clicked
    ********/
function takePicture() {
    var result = blackberry.media.camera.takePicture(successCB);
}


/*******
post processing of photo click event
********/
function successCB(filePath) {
   try{
    blackberry.media.camera.close();
    var imagePath = "file://" + filePath;
    document.getElementById('images').setAttribute('src', imagePath.toString());
    document.getElementById("photoDetails").innerHTML = imagePath;
   }
  catch(e) {
        document.getElementById("photoDetails").innerHTML = e.ToString();
  }
}
//ConfigFile includes the following,  <access subdomains="false" uri="file:///store/home/user/camera/">

       //html portion of viewing photo
       <ul>
            <li id="Li1">
                <img id="Img1" alt="image" src="file:///store/home/user/camera/IMG-20120118-00001.jpg" /></li>
            <li id="photoDetails">
                <img id="images" alt="image" src="kkkoj" /></li>
        </ul>
```

the imagePath variable successfully prints => "file:///store/home/user/camera/IMG-20120118-00001.jpg". but the photo is not showing up.

i don't understand whats the problem with the code i have written. image path came alright.

Strangely when i hardcode the imagePath as a src of image it can show the image. but when i set it using javascript in successCB(), it doesn't work. i tested the functionality of my javascript code in firefox. it works in basic html. i am using Blackberry 9700 with os 6 bundle 2921. i need immediate help. please i am stuck with this for a whole day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're use of `document.getElementById("photoDetails").innerHTML` is the problem. `.innerHTML` replaces everything in between the opening and closing tags of `<li id="photoDetails">`. Since `images` is in `photoDetails`, it is getting erased with just the imagePath.

If you want to display the imagePath, try adding a `<div>` or `<span>` and updating them with the path.

Also, I don't think you need the `<access>` element in your configuration file, since that is only used for accessing external servers.

Comment: thanks core.B for correcting me. i knew, but it didn't come to my mind. have a nice day